# From terminal mode (live USB) I need to know cleanest way to remove bootup problem: boot: gfxboot.c32 not a com32r image

Tags: boot, usb

After a problematic install of 20.04 LTS involving partitioning issues corrupting the bootloader I need to know what to fix through terminal mode.

I get the message at bootup:

boot: gfxboot.32c not a com32r image

By using the tab key and typing "live" (enter) I can get the system to finish booting from the bootable zipdrive. The power on boot process does this whether I change the BIOS to boot from the Hard drive or USB drive. So something in the bootloader is not right and needs correcting.

Comment: The fix is backups (if not done yet) and properly install Ubuntu 20.04 or newer.

Comment: I am confused.  gfxboot.32c was a typo, right? (should be gfxboot.c32)  Anyway, that file is a syslinux module, and the message can result from the wrong version of the file.  See other  answers here on how Startup Disk Creator can grab the wrong version instead of using the correct one from the ISO.  Fix was use another burning tool, even just dd. But your posting seems to indicate the problem arises from the install, not the install media.

Comment: yes, a typo....

Answer (score 0):

Boot-Repair resolved bootloader problems.....